# Do stars amplify or refract gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, refraction, gravitational-waves

I am curious if stars (or other massive bodies) amplify or refract [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) in a manner similar to the following.

**Amplification**
In the case of amplification, do massive bodies affect gravitational waves similar to the steepening that occurs in [shallow water waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations) during runup near shore?  Or can massive bodies act like a pump to locally amplify (or damp) the waves?
[image: Propagation of a tsunami offshore, showing the variation of wavelength and amplitude as a function of depth (Courtesy of Régis Lachaume on Wikipedia Commons).]

**Refraction**
In the case of [refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction), I am wondering if massive bodies act like (in a very loose, analogous way) obstacles in water for water waves (e.g., see animation below)?
[image: Propagation of periodic waves over an elliptic underwater shoal on a uniform beach. The computations have been made using a Boussinesq-type model, and show the effects of wave refraction, diffraction and shoaling on the wave field (Courtesy of Kraaiennest on Wikipedia Commons).]

I realize that gravitational waves are quadrapolar, not mono- or dipolar but I do not think that renders them immune to similar effects if they truly are waves.

**Update**
After some searching, the closest thing to an answer that I could find was a paper by [*Peters* [1974]](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1974PhRvD...9.2207P) that treats the index of refraction for gravitational waves as a scalar, which seems problematic for addressing a quadrapolar mode.

Comment: This is a cool question. I doubt that something very massive doesn't do something to the waves, but have no idea what.

Comment: Why would a scalar index of refraction be any more problematic for quadrupole radiation than for a dipole radiation (i.e., Maxwell's equations in matter?)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - Fair point.  I guess I am used to plasmas where the susceptibility is a tensor and the  index of refraction is a vector at minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do stars amplify or refract gravitational waves?

Not to any extent that could be measured. When a gravitational wave comes to a star, it has traveled a distance of at least on the order of a light-year from the source, so its amplitude is small. The gravitational field of a star is also near the weak-field limit. In the weak-field limit, the Einstein field equations, which are nonlinear, behave approximately linearly. Therefore the field of the star does not interact significantly with the field of the wave.